# Firebase offline persistence Flutter Delete

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I have offline persistence working for my chat app in flutter.

I was hoping when I delete/purge data on the firebase console, the saved data will be still stored in the phone storage. It seems this is not the case at all.

Is there a workaround for this? like an Override?(delete from server/backend but keep it on the local storage)

My other option would be this:

Convert incoming data from firebase into sqflite database schema. Display the Sqflite data onto user display as listview

Keeping data stored on the firebase to minimal.
(build in a sent flag, to make sure users received the message before purging it in backend)

would this be real time enough for multiple people in a group chat? because of the added steps to display messages?

OR

Keep displaying incoming firebase messages on users phone(for real time)
The data is still in backend.
Update users local storage and back up old messages every 2 weeks.
Delete backend data.

for this last option, how can i Merge old messages(sqflite) with current messages(firebase)? Will sorting the sqflite chat messages by timestamps and display them along with firebase, be fine?

Thank you
-F.T

Comment: Basic answer on the reasons for the database's behavior below. It's hard to answer your other questions, because they're very broad right now. You'll find that the answers you get on Stack Overflow get more concrete, as you give a more concrete question. For example: what concrete problem do you have with the performance? Do you have code and logging output to illustrate?

Answer (score 0):

Both databases that are part of Firebase (Realtime Database, and Cloud Firestore) are primarily cloud-hosted databases that continue to work when your app is temporarily not connected to the cloud. They are not designed to be used as purely standalone databases.

There may be tricks to keep Firebase from purging local data. For example, I've seen developers mark the user as offline after an initial synchronization of the Realtime Database. But while such an approach may work in the short term, since they go against the intent of the database, they're likely to lead to problems down the line.

Comment: Hey Frank, thank you for the response. I know i am a bit late to this. I have been working dearly on my flutter app. I have concluded for my app's future to not save the data locally via SQLFLITE plugin. I will also post an answer below how to get the input stream data from firebase into SQL and some pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

how to get an incoming stream of data from backend such as Firebase real time database into local storage via Sqflite plugin:

Some problems I need to and want to list:
Using a statefulwidget which keeps rebuilding whenever set state is in code and when leaving/entering back into the statefulwidget(also happens in statelesswidget) refreshes the stream

this problem causes data to be saved into SQFLITE as duplicate data

you can do this, make a button and when you press it.. this code will execute:
rough code: not complete. I did not test this exact code I just wrote

```
Timestamp _timeStamp = previousSyncTimeStamp;
FlatButton(
 child: Text('Sync Data'),
 onPressed: () {
     syncData(_timeStamp);
     Timestamp previousSyncTimeStamp = currentTime;
     }
)

void syncData() {
        FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('yourChild')
        .startAt(_timeStamp)

    //this is your incoming data stream from a back end.
    //then with your created Sqflite schema in your flutter app

    //grab the snapshot data from the stream and put it into your object(sqflite)

        Object someObj = Object(snapshot.value['someValue'], snapshot.value['someOtherValue']);
        var dbHelper = DBHelper();
        dbHelper.saveObject(someObj);
}
```

now you synced firebase backend with local sqflite without duplicate..playing around with the timeStamp to make sure you dont miss out on anything.